# Synchronize on read operations?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety, jetty

I am going through the jetty code and I came across this function in **ShutdownMonitor**:

```
private final Set<LifeCycle> _lifeCycles = new LinkedHashSet<>();

private boolean containsLifeCycle(LifeCycle lifeCycle)
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        return _lifeCycles.contains(lifeCycle);
    }
}
```

Similarly,

```
 public int getPort()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            return port;
        }
    }
```

There are several other functions which add/remove a lifecyle. It's fine that they be synchronized (**and they are**). But why do we need synchronized on functions which will only involve read?

Comment: If you only sync on writing; and your writes/reads aren't atomic; maybe the locking is required to ensure that reads give you consistent results (instead of giving you some half-baked write, that isn't completely through yet). (but that is more of "generic gut feeling"; as I am not familiar with this component)

Comment: Ya, but the writing and reading synchronized blocks are not monitored on the _lifeCycle object. So if a thread is currently writing to _lifeCycle, containsLifeCycle will still be executed. If we wanted to do what you are saying, we should have synchronized on the _lifeCycle object.

Comment: Let’s ask the other way round: *Why do you think you don’t need them for read access?* Any documentation, tutorial or specification will tell you that you *always* need proper synchronization, so it’s not useful to discuss why a rule that does not exist does not apply here…

Comment: @Holger I think what you are referring to is the point that if a thread is writing to the set and if another thread reads it, it can read some garbage data. Basically, when there is  write going on, we want to block the reads. But in the present scenario we are monitoring on object this and not in the data structure. So write and read can happen concurrently anyway. So what is the purpose of synchronized then?

Comment: The phrase “*we are monitoring on object this and not in the data structure*” makes no sense. A “monitor” is just a critical section of code that can be executed by at most a single thread only. Which object is used, is completely irrelevant, as long as it is the *same* object for all critical sections. Since all methods consistently use `this`, there can be only one thread accessing the data structure, assuming that it stays `private`, i.e. no other references to it exist.

Comment: Ok. So this means that when I am monitoring on this object, even if the code segments are different, one thread (executing lets say read) would be locked if another thread executing a different function(say write) is synchronized on the same object?

Comment: Exactly, all `synchronized` blocks using the same object instance, share the same monitor, thus, are mutually exclusive. Likewise, non-`static` methods declared `synchronized` acquire the `this` specific monitor. So all object structures, like an embedded `Set` are safe, as long as no thread is accessing it without first acquiring the monitor. That’s why it is a good idea to declare all fields `private`. But at the same time, the same code might be executed for a different instance, but then, it will use a different `Set` instance as well.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. So what do we do about this question? You can this as an answer so that I can accept it.